# preprocessing in spring boot batch with multiple threads

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-batch

I have a Spring batch with multi threads. In my processor I want to use global variables say a map. The map contains some values which is to be queried from a table and is to be used by the processor. How can I achieve this? If i write the logic to set the map in the processor, the query will be executed for every record fetched by the item reader, which would be millions in numbers. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept step execution

[Spring Batch - Reference Documentation section 5.1.10. Intercepting Step Execution](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#stepExecutionListener)

For example, you can implement the StepExecutionListener interface

```
@Component
@JobScope
public class Processor implements ItemProcessor<Integer,Integer>, StepExecutionListener {

    private final Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        // initialize a variable once before step
        map.put("KEY","VALUE");
    }

    @Override
    public Integer process(Integer item) throws Exception {
        // use a variable for each iteration
        final String key = map.get("KEY");
        // ...
    }

    // ....
}
```

or use the @BeforeStep annotation

```
@Component
@JobScope
public class Processor implements ItemProcessor<Integer,Integer>{

    private final Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        // initialize a variable once before step
        map.put("KEY","VALUE");
    }

    @Override
    public Integer process(Integer item) throws Exception {
        // use a variable for each iteration
        final String key = map.get("KEY");
        //...
    }
}
```